# rotate sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence:

1, 3, 7, 9

You can think of it as the 4 corners of a square:

[image]

I want to turn this sequence 1 step to the right so it becomes

[image]

And also turn it left:

[image]

What is the equation to do that?

Edit since it got downvoted by Adam Wrzesiński for not understanding it's use:

[image]

Rotating the numbers circled in blue one step to the right gives the number in the side squares that the blue line is drawn to.

10 - the corner numbers in the middle produces the number in the corner opposite to them (in the red circle)

the circled red numbers divived by 2 produces the number in yellow.

The number in green are the same corner numbers again that we circled in blue, but this time they are turned left from their original position.

This gives me all the numbers in the grid that are adjacent to the corner numbers in the middle square.

I thought I would simplyfy it down to the core problem, because staring at all the grid numbers might be a bit too distracting.

Comment: What do you need this equation for?. We have to interpret this as a sequence of vectors?, permutations, matrices...

Comment: There we go, I edited the question, do you understand it's purpose now?

I am after all the numbers in the grid that are in the outer ring that are adjecent to the corners in the midle square.

Corner 1 should produce something like:
tile_4[3]
tile_4[6]
tile_1[9]
tile_2[7]
tile_2[8]

this will give me the information I need for coding some features in my grid. I could very easilly go with constant values for each corner, but this posed a very interesting problem that I didn't know how to solve mathematically and as such I wanted to learn how to do it.